# How to setup products for eye glasses store - bundle of configurable products?

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product

I want to setup a eyeglasses store which will sell frame+Lens as a bundle.

**Lens** - has around 11 attributes (spherical, cylindrical, index, surface coating, etc) with lots of values totaling to ~5000 combinations for it.

**Frames** - Will be around 200.
I could think of following solutions
**Option 1** - setup each Frame+lens as a configurable product with 5000 simple products for attribute combinations
Front-end show perfectly with frame on left and lens attributes on right for selection. But problem is I will end up with 1 million simple products (200 frames each having 5000 simple products) and updating prices every 2-3 months will be a nightmare. Plus not sure if the system will work well with so many products loaded.

**Option 2** - Setup Lens as a configurable product and Frame as a simple product and somehow allow customer to purchase it only as a bundle.
The option 2 is looking more sensible to me but problem is Magento is not supporting bundle of 1 simple + 1 configurable product.

Is there any other other way to setup these products ?